# Posting complex types with WebApi Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the WebApi Client to post to a WebApi test project.  My post method on my controller accepts a single parameter (a model).

If I post using JSON, it all works. If I post using XML, the parameter is always null. Is this a bug?

```
var client = new HttpClient();
// on the server side, the loan param will be null
var response = client.PostAsXmlAsync(
    "http://localhost.fiddler:54835/api/Loan/PostLoan", 
    new Loan() { LoanId = 1 }).Result;

// on the server side, the loan param is just fine
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(
    "http://localhost.fiddler:54835/api/Loan/PostLoan", 
    new Loan() { LoanId = 1 }).Result;
```

The only difference between the 2 calls is that in one I'm calling `PostAsXmlAsync`, and in the other, I'm calling `PostAsJsonAsync`.

Here's the sig for my controller (I'm using action based routing):

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostLoan(Loan loan)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(loan.LoanId);
}
```

And here's my test model:

```
public class Loan
{
    public int LoanId { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my routing:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are using separate classes in Web API and the client app. If you look at the request XML, you will see a namespace like so. I just use `MyNamespace` for illustration.

```
<Loan xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace">
    <LoanId>1</LoanId>
</Loan>
```

The namespace in the request must match that of the class you use in the action parameter, for `DataContractSerializer` to work.

Say, your `Loan` class in Web API has the namespace of `MyWebApiProject.MyModels`. In the client application, your `Loan` class will need to be like this, if it's namespace is not `MyWebApiProject.MyModels`.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWebApiProject.MyModels")]
    public class Loan
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int LoanId { get; set; }
    }
```

If you want to share DTO, it is a good idea to separate them out into a project and reference them in both the client and Web API and you will have consistency in the namespaces that way.

Comment: That's an excellent guess and what a noob mistake!  I know better when I'm working with WCF, but I didn't consider that webapi is using the Datacontract serializer under the covers, so of course namespace matters!  Thanks.